# How to Override the behaviour of Devise Remeberable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am very new to rails and we have application that uses Devise authentication and we use remeberable feature which we want to override it from the behavior of "keep me logged in" to the behavior of "saving user credentials on the login page inside input fields"  so anybody have an idea how to implement this behavior? any idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you want to save user login and pass on a login page? In case 'yes' --  that's a big security question

Comment: that is exactly what we want

Comment: and you don't care about security stuff?

Comment: yes i care for sure, i persuaded my team to accept the current behavior. thanks @ted